# Missing required parameters for [Route: ticket.edit] [URI: ticket_ads/edit/{ad}]

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to edit a record in a table. I have created a route and the form, but I can't get past this error. I have figured out the problem but I can't find a fix. Am I correct in thinking that the `edit.blade.php` file needs the `$ad->id` passing?

The `$ad->id` is an ID of a specific add in a List View. The list view has all the tickets displayed from a table, and the below link is meant to edit that one item.

The edit route is accessed using following code:

```
<a href="{{ route('ticket.edit', $ad->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

I have one route that is supposed to open up the edit view form:

```
Route::get('/ticket_ads/edit/{ad}', 'TicketAdsController@editTicketAdForm')->name('ticket.edit');
```

The above route points to this in the controller:

```
  public function editTicketAdForm($id)
  {
      //$ad = DB::table('ticket_ads')->where('id', $id)->value('id');
      return view('Ads.edit')->with('id', $id);
  }
```

This is the view called by the above function:

```
@extends('Shared.Layouts.MasterWithoutMenus')

@section('title')
Edit a ticket ad
@stop

@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Edit your ticket ad</h2></div>   <br/>

        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

        {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'ticket.edit', $id = 'id')) }}

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('title', 'Title') }}
            {{ Form::text('title', Input::old('title'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('comment', 'Comment') }}
            {{ Form::text('comment', Input::old('comment'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>

        {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

        {{ Form::close() }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
@endsection
```

This is the line that throws the error

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'ticket.edit', $id = 'id')) }}
```

The ID displays normally in the URL as `ticket_ads/edit/7` for example.

How do I get past this?

Comment: You have defined route as GET `Route::get()`. While in `<form action` it seems as POST request. Is it correct. Try to share things related to GET request.

Comment: I changed it to `<a href="...">` with the same route and the same error occurs, so I doubt it's that.

Comment: It needs to be more clear. Please share more code. You share this line {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'ticket.edit', $id)) }},  also this one  <form action="{{ route('ticket.edit', $ad->id) }}">, its not clear which is making problem. Remove code which is irrelevant, and try to expand more code that could be more concerned.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to share. What would you like me to share? I've added more code to the view section. I've added more explanation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'ticket.edit', $id = 'id')) }}
```

to this:

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => array('ticket.edit', $id)))}}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'ticket.edit', $id = 'id')) }}
```

is wrong. Correct syntax is:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['ticket.edit', $id]]) }}
```

also you should safely ditch using `array()` in favor of `[]` syntax as Laravel requires PHP 5.4+ anyway (unless you are using ancient version of Laravel, like v4?)

Comment: It still gives the error. I'm on Laravel 5.2.45. Would be updating but this isn't going into production.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for calling route is.

```
{{ route('/cardetails', ['121','cars'] ) }}
```

In URL it will be like this below line.

```
127.0.0.1:8000/cardetails/121/cars
```